# Configuring HTTPS on elastic beanstalk (single instance) of Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have configured https on load balancer for testing that was easy, Adding your certificate and key contents directly to the configuration file is acceptable for testing with self-signed certificates. For production use, I need to upload these files to a secure S3 bucket, then use the configuration file to download these files from the bucket when the instance is provisioned. i have already followed this link [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html#storing-certs
but still i cannot do the thing can any one help me out with this

Comment: "but still i cannot do the thing" isn't really a valid question. Where exactly are you encountering issues? Is there an error message you are getting at some point? Are there errors during deployment? Is there anything in the server log? You have to provide us details if you expect us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: sorry mark for my rude questioning let me tell you what exactly is happening i have added e extension file to source bundle this eb extension file contains two configuration files one is to activate port 443 for  https another is for downloading keys from s3 bucket to elastic beanstalk in /etc/pki/tls/certs/ location after selecting the option build with parameters in jenkins the build is successful but still i cant see the keys in the /etc/pki/tls/certs/. there is no sign of keys downloading from s3 in access logs for beanstalk

Comment: I have written a bucket policy in s3                                                     {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"},
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.188/32"} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}